# Addtional LED lightstrips for cars

Tags: electrical, lights, led

I am looking to add extra LED light strips to my car to be used as DRL. The car currently have DRLs that will switch off when the headlights are turned on. I want to have the new light strips always on. I tried connecting the current DRL circuit and headlight circuit together so the light strips will always be on. The problem I am having is when the headlights are switched on,the current DRL will not switch off. How can I use these two circuit without it bleeding to the other. I am just starting to learn about automotive wiring. I would appreciate all advice on how to accomplish this.

Comment: @DaveTweed - That's a great answer ... you should treat it as such.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them "always on", why would you connect the new strips to the headlight/DRL circuits at all? Just connect them directly to the switched 12V accessory bus, through a fuse.